# How to open a jar by default?

Tags: macos, mac, java

I had a question "How do I run a jar when double-click it?" But now I know that my computer is not set to open jars by default. Is there a settings in the mac that open jars by default? All the jars that I tried to open is not working. Do I need a program to make it open by default? *I use terminal to open it*

Comment: Do you have Java installed on your Mac so you can run the Jar?  Or are you wanting to open a Jar to edit it?

Comment: I just want to open a jar. I don't need to edit(I'm a developer) I have a jar luncher though.. I opened it with it but only shows a window then disappears!

Comment: Thanks for narrowing that down.  I found this "You can edit jar files by using WinRar. Right click on file and choose Open with Winrar. Then you can edit Manifest file in Notepad or edit image files with Paint. The main features of the application are saved as class files, editing them causes the application to be useless."